# Linux Move txt files not start with String to Another folder

Tags: linux, move

The situation is
I have a directory A, I have a bunch of files and folders in the foldler. 
 Such as folder B , foler C , tmp1.txt , Hello.txt , tmp3.txt , okay.txt.
And in folder B,there are also a bunch of files in it.
So I want to move all txt files recrusively to another folder such as /home.
Here is my code.

```
find . -name "*.txt"| grep -v [\s\S]*tmp[\s\S]* -exec mv {} /home \;
```

I can only select these files,however it won't execute move operation.

[image]

because linux find has path in result.So it annoy me a lot.

Comment: **note:** on a Unix/Linux system, you probably do not what to clutter up `/home` with a bunch of text files. `/home` is a specific FHS required directory that holds the user home directories within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move only regular files, add `-type f` and exclude the files you don't want with `\!`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' \! -name '*tmp*' -exec mv -i -t /home {} +
```

The `-i` asks for permission to overwrite a file if it already exists and the `+` instead of the `\;` is used to move as many files as possible with one invocation of `mv`  (and thus we need to specify the target directory with the `-t` option as `{}` contains more than one file).